# How can I pass variable data from Controller to app.blade.php in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-7

I want to pass the query's result to the template (I have a section in my template where I show the number of rows (count) of each table) so inside my controller I have this function:

```
public function dashboardInfos()
{
    $infos = DB::select("SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) from patients ) AS P, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rendez_vouses) AS R, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ordonnances) AS O, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM consultations) AS C");   

    foreach($infos as $i)
    {
        View::share([
        'P' => $i->P, 
        'R' => $i->R, 
        'O' => $i->O, 
        'C' => $i->C]);
    }

}
```

and inside the app.blade.php I put : `{{ $i->P }}`

the error I'm getting is "Undefined variable: i "

How can I resolve this ?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there is no variable named `i` ... you named them `P, R, O, C`

Comment: Did you call `dashboardInfos()` and its controller?

Comment: if you want this information available every time `app.blade.php` layout is used I would use a View Composer

Comment: but when I use it it gives me undefined variable underline in vscode 2019 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by deleteing the function inside the controller which is dashboardInfos() and I went to AppServiceProvider inside the boot function and I wrote this code:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('infos', DB::select("SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) from patients ) AS P, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rendez_vouses) AS R, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ordonnances) AS O, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM consultations) AS C"));
}
```

and inside the app.blade.php I wrote this:

```
@foreach ($infos as $i)
   <h2 class="text-dark mb-1 font-weight-medium">{{ $i->P }}</h2>
@endforeach
```

Comment: use a view composer ... you are going to run into problems when you go to deploy this unless the entire database is already setup for you where it is deployed because you are asking the framework to make that database query every time it boots which includes when the commands are ran ... if you want to run migrations to create these tables you won't be able to because of DB exception you will get

Answer (score -1):

use return view('name-blade-template', compact('varname'));
compact('varname') same as 'varname'=>$varname

Comment: then you can put on the blade template {{$varname}}

Comment: I want this to show up in all pages  how can I do that ?

Comment: in that case check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers